# Using ssh, what is the best way to download a massive amount of files

Tags: download, copy, wildcard, sftp, transfer

I am attempting to write a bash script and only using the ssh protocol (sftp, scp), what is the best way to download a massive amount of files. I am talking like 10,000+.

What happens when I bash script using sftp, sftp only sees 500 at a time. In a very primitive sort of way, I keep running `mget *.*` until I have downloaded all the files.

curl does sftp but not wildcard/multiple files.

wget does multiple files but not sftp.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I've never see the 500 files limitation. What is your SFTP server? What happens, if you use `ls` command? Does it also show only 500 files, even if there are more?

Comment: When you do a `mget *.*`, it takes a moment to load and then downloads 500 at a time. The server knows I have downloaded those 500 and flips a switch on them. When I run `mget *.*` again, it will get a fresh 500 files and again.

Is it possible to write a loop with the sftp command prompt?

Comment: So the 500 limit is some custom functionality deliberately built into your SFTP server?

Answer (score 0):

scp recursive option allows you to download and upload any number of files.

**scp -r root@my.web.server.com:/var/www/* /var/www/local**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp -r "user@example.com:/home/santhosh/" /u01/dumps
#######################
expect {
  -re ".*es.*o.*" {
    exp_send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "PASSWORD\r"
  }
}
```

Try this above as well, code snippet from the link below
https://blogs.oracle.com/SanthoshK/entry/automate_linux_scp_command

you could also look into rsync to download files from server if server has rsync installed
**rsync**

**rsync -a username@remote_host:/home/username/dir1 place_to_sync_on_local_machine**

Comment: It's even easier than that since I am doing ssh keys for no entry... so expect wouldn't necessarily be used.

Comment: I myself have not used expect, but saw the posting and I thought that might be what you were looking for. I have used with ssh keys, they work great.

Answer (score 0):

```
scp username@server:path/to/remote/dir/* /path/to/local/dir
```

And if I wanted to do everything recursive:

```
scp -r username@server:path/to/remote/dir/* /path/to/local/dir
```

This was a million times better than what I had running in my little bash script.

Thank you so much.